# Python 'cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' on Raspbian

Tags: python, linux, debian, raspbian

I am trying to install [pvrecorder](https://pypi.org/project/pvrecorder/) on a Virtual Machine with Raspbian installed. I got some Python script that records the user's microphone, until `KeyboardInterrupt` is triggered (user presses `Ctrl` + `C`). I already tested it on my Windows machine and everything worked smoothly. The problem is, I get some error after running the script, and this comes from the installed `pvrecorder`.

The Raspbian is an **x86** build.

First, I am creating a Virtual Environment with the command:
`python3 -m venv venv` and activating it using `source venv/bin/activate`.

Then, I am installing **pvrecorder** with `pip3 install pvrecorder`. Everything works smoothly.

Problem is, when I am trying to run my **script.py**, which begins with this line:

```
from pvrecorder import PvRecorder
```

this is the error I receive:

```
OSerror: /home/pi/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pvrecorder/lib/linux/i686/libpv_recorder.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried **NOT** installing `pvrecorder` in a separately-created venv, but directly, without activating any specific virtual environment. When I look inside `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pvrecorder/lib/linux/`, I don't see any `i686` folder, but an `x64_86` folder that contains my `.so` file.

When I try to copy that `.so` file into a newly-created `i686` folder, it gives me another error when trying to launch `script.py`:

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I read some other similar Stack Overflow answers, and users were told that it may be because of the fact that I am using an x86 OS for an x64 library, but pvrecorder's website states that their module is available for both x86 and x64 Raspbian builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually compiling `pvrecorder` seems to have fixed the job.

The problem is, the pip installation always resulted in an `x64` library output. I needed an `x86` one.

First, I needed to clone the [pvrecorder repository](https://github.com/Picovoice/pvrecorder).

Then, I installed `cmake`:

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

and then I compiled the module (follow [this link](https://github.com/Picovoice/pvrecorder#compiling) - official GitHub repo - and head over to the "Compiling" section).

After compiling the module, you need to copy the generated `.so` file from `pvrecorder/build/` (which is the cloned repository with the generated `build` folder resulted from compilation) to the path:

`/home/pi/Desktop/proj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pvrecorder/lib/linux/i686`
(I manually created folder `i686`).

This means, you also need to install the module in your env via `pip`.